# How to add new column to R dataframe based on values in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created the following dataframe

```
 df<-data.frame("A"<-(1:5), "B"<-c("A","B", "C", "B",'C' ), "C"<-c("A", "A", 
"B", 'B', "B"))
names(df)<-c("A", "B", "C")
```

I am triyng to obtain the duplicated values between columns A and C following output and add the corresponding values in column B . The expected dataframe should be

```
    df2<- "B"   "Dupvalues"
           1      A
            4     B
```

I am unable to do this. I request some help here

Comment: There's something wrong with your desired data.frame code

Comment: I think you mean "obtain the duplicated values between columns B and C"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df<-data.frame(A = (1:5), 
               B = c("A","B", "C", "B",'C' ), 
               C = c("A", "A","B", 'B', "B"), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(B == C) %>%           # keep rows when B equals C
  group_by(A) %>%              # for each A
  transmute(DupValues = B) %>% # keep the duplicate value
  ungroup()                    # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#       A DupValues
#   <int> <chr>    
# 1     1 A        
# 2     4 B
```

Note that this works if your variables are not factors, but character varaibles.

Comment: Thank you. Is there some way that the filter command can be extended to include multiple columns ie more than 2

Comment: Yes, there should be an option, but it will be good to provide an example with 3+ columns and your ideal output first.

Comment: Will revise the code and repost sir. This is very helpful so far though. Thank you